# Проблема с ViewModel kotlin

Tags: android-fragment, kotlin, viewmodel

пишу простенькое приложение заметок, столкнулся с проблемой, но ничего не помогает. Проблема я так понял с ViewModelProviders, помогите пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал, не понимаю что не так

Фрагмент:

```
 private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Заметки"
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    val adapter = RecyclerAdapter()
    recycler_view.adapter = adapter
    noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).
     get(NoteViewModel::class.java)// Здесь ставится курсор ошибки
    noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, Observer<List<Notes>> {})
    add_note.setOnClickListener {
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(
            R.id.fl_content,
            AddNoteFragment()
        )?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class NoteViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {
private var repository: NoteRepository =
    NoteRepository(application)
private var allNotes: LiveData<List<Notes>> = repository.getAllNotes()

fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Notes>> {
    return allNotes
}
```

Код ошибки:

```
rocess: com.example.testapp, PID: 3791
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.firstapp.NoteViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:184)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:241)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
    at com.example.firstapp.RecyclerViewFragment.onViewCreated(RecyclerViewFragment.kt:33)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2938)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.firstapp.NoteViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:182)
```

Comment: Что не так? В чём проблема то?

Comment: Не запускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что ваша ViewModel не имеет конструктора без параметров. Сгенерированный по умолчанию фабричный класс может создавать модели только через вызов пустого конструктора.

Вам нужно создать свой фабричный класс, например так:

```
class NoteViewModelFactory(val application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(NoteViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return NoteViewModel(application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

и при создании экземпляра указать эту "фабрику"

```
val viewModelFactory = NoteViewModelFactory(application)
noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
```